# Executing all javascript in a .js after clicking a button on a chrome extension (not just one function)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am new to javascript and there are many resources, but they are hard to use given my constraint of working on a chrome extension.

Chrome extensions do not allow javvascript code in the HTML except in this form:

```
<script language="javascript" src="login.js"></script>
```

Right now, I have login.js running and passing some info to an API. This happens right when the HTML loads which is caused by the user clicking the chrome button.

The HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme"/>
    <script language="javascript" src="login.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This page displays after the user clicks the extension button and it immediately runs the login.js script.

**I would like it to only run the login.js after the button clickme has been pressed.**

login.js consists of:

```
document.write("<br />" + "From login" + "<br />");
var output;
output = FunctionOne();
document.write("<br /> the output:  " + output + "<br />");

function FunctionOne() {
  var xhr = 
...
  return xhr;
}
function FunctionTwo() {
  var cat 
...
  return cat;
}
```

Comment: You could create function in the login.js function which calls all other functions. Then call that big function in the button

Comment: What about the code that is not in a function? @javaguest

Comment: put that in the function too. Like in Teepeemm's answer, just add function myFunction () { at the beginning of your .js file and one } at the end, which will encapsulate everything as a callable function from the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your first few lines in a function:

```
function writeOutput() {
    document.write("<br />" + "From login" + "<br />");
    var output;
    output = FunctionOne();
    document.write("<br /> the output:  " + output + "<br />");
}
```

Then everything in login.js is function defintions, so nothing will run when the code it loaded.  To get something to happen, attach a listener to clickme in login.js:

```
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click',writeOutput);
```

By the way, you shouldn’t be using `document.write`.  Instead, have some placeholder `div`s in your html, and call `document.getElementById('myDiv').textContent = 'stuff'`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am running your code and getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).attachEventListener is not a function @Teepeemm

Comment: Sorry.  Should be `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the javascript "eval" function.  eval allows you to run arbitrary code from a string.  So if you can grab the text from the login.js document, and then save it as a string, you can run eval on it.

For example:

**// contents of this examples login.js file**

```
 console.log(2+2)
```

**// contents of the main javascript file running the code**

```
var some_text_to_eval = get_text_from_file('login.js');
eval(some_text_to_eval);  // this should console log the number 4
```

---

*The method provided above is a direct answer to your question.  If you want to use an easier method, use the jQuery library.  It has a "click" event that allows you to execute code after something has been clicked on: https://api.jquery.com/click/*

```
 $('#clickMe').on('click', function(){
      // do some work
      console.log('test')
 })
```

Comment: 1. `eval` is evil and should be avoided at all costs. 2. Anything jQuery can do, regular javascript can do; it just may take a longer command.